# Connectig to sFTP Server using SSH public/private key. Error {Invalid private key file.} Using SSH.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, sftp, openssh, ssh.net

Firstly I generated the keys using

```
var keygen = new SshKeyGenerator.SshKeyGenerator(2048);

var privateKey = keygen.ToPrivateKey();
var publicSshKey = keygen.ToRfcPublicKey();
```

The private key generated the following string:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBA... etc.
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm now trying to create a new Renci.SshNet.PrivateKeyFile object to be used to create the SftpClient object. I tried loading the RSA private Key string in a number of ways similar to:

```
using (var keyStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ReturnKey())))
{
    var privateKy = new PrivateKeyFile(keyStream);

}
```

The method ReturnKey() simply returns a string of the private key -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- etc. I've tried with and without the "-----BEGIN RSA and -----End RSA" and I get the same result:

> Error {Invalid private key file.}

I have all the details to connect to sFTP server i.e. User, DNS, Port, Path. which has the public key generated, I just can't load the private key as a start.

This is the first time I've had to connect to sFTP using SSH. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show all of the relevant code from your program, in particular the code which is producing the error. Ideally, you should post a complete, simple program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `new PrivateKeyFile(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(new SshKeyGenerator.SshKeyGenerator(2048).ToPrivateKey())))` does not throw any exception for me (I've used NuGet packages SshKeyGenerator 1.1.40 and SSH.NET 2020.0.1).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl this also worked for me, so it must be the way I'm storing the privatekey and resuing it, I'll try a few things initially.

Comment: @Kenster fair point, I'll add all the relevant code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like it was the way I was adding the private key text; instead I saved the key to a txt file and loaded directly. I think there were additional characters, tabs/returns perhaps in the string from ReturnKey() function, so it would have helped if I added the full code.